# How to convert a void * into a usable type using enum

Tags: c, pointers, struct, enums

So I have a structure that contains two things:

1. `void *` to a value.
2. `enum Types type` that specifies what type the pointer is pointing to.

```c
enum Types { CHAR, INT };

struct MyStructure {
  void *value;
  enum Types type;
}
```

I wanted to get the value of the `void *`, to do that I need something that indicates what is the type of the pointer, I have an **enum** (`enum Types { CHAR, INT }`) their value(the possibles types) can be either a `CHAR` or a `INT` which should be converted to `char` and `int` C types respectively, but how can I do this?

I could use an `if else` statement to check the enum types and convert the **value** to the right type, like:

```c
if (my_structure.type == CHAR) char *value_with_type = (char *)value;
else if (my_structure.type == INT) int *value_with_type = (int *)value;
```

But doing like that would mean that if I wanted to expand the types in the future, I would have to also change the `if else` to be able to convert the new types.

**Is it possible to do what I'm saying?**

Comment: "Is it possible to do what I'm saying?" --> Yes.  To do well, we need to see the larger usage.  Note: cast not needed as `value` is a `void *`.  `char *value_with_type = (char *)value;` --> `char *value_with_type = value;`.

Comment: Note that the 'if' example you show would not work, the char* value_with_type will be defined locally in each if/else branch, and go out of scope when the if exits. You would have to define each of the variables for the different types before the if block. Also the logic has to know the variable it is using. You could use helper functions to wrap of lot of this up and then it would create hard-to-follow code. What is the actually problem  you are trying to solve? there may be a much better solution.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but you *will* typically need explicit cases in your if/else tree (or switch statement) to handle each datatype you want to manage.

Comment: @Chris I'm trying to make an Array structure, it has a `int length`, a `void *list` and a `enum ArrayTypes type`, the list should point to items of the same type, defined by the type property, should I use an union to store the list instead and the type property will define what item is being used in the union?

Comment: Does the list need to be ordered as added? Can you use multiple lists or just one? Also probably dont want to store pointers but instead the values themselves and have functions to return value by type

Comment: @Chris The list has a fixed length and one type for all items.